# Changing height of UIView in response to finger drag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I understand that the title is a bit confusing so I'll try my best to explain it well. I have a UIView that has a fixed width of 100, and a variable height that starts at 0. What I want to be able to do is drag my finger from the base of the UIView, towards the top of the screen, and the UIView changes its height/extends to the position of my finger. If that's still to complicated just imagine it as a strip of paper being pulled out from under something.

If you can help, that would be really great. I don't think it should be too hard, but I'm only a beginner and I can understand if I haven't explained it well!

Comment: I would make the view always full height, but have a CALayer inside the view who's height changes.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Have you looked at gesture recognisers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should be straight-forward with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and a little math. To change the view to the correct frame (I'm using the name `_viewToChange`, so replace that with your view later), simply add:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer * pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[self addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

to your `init` method for the super view, and define the method:

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)aPan; {
  CGPoint currentPoint = [aPan locationInView:self];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.01f
                   animations:^{
                     CGRect oldFrame = _viewToChange.frame;
                     _viewToChange.frame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, currentPoint.y, oldFrame.size.width, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - currentPoint.y));
                   }];
}
```

This should animate the view up as the users finger moves. Hope that Helps!

Comment: That works, thank you! Do you know how I could add a max and a min to the view's height?

Comment: Also, there is another slight problem. The code works, but it works no matter where you touch the screen. This is a bit of a problem because I will be having 3 of these. Is there any way you can change it so it only works for a certain view when you are touching it?

Comment: A max and a min are easy enough. Notice that the only point that matters is `currentPoint.y`. Making sure that `currentPoint.y` is within some interval (using the `MAX` and `MIN` functions) will give you the desired result.

As for the view you want it to select, simply look at the `currentPoint.x`, and figure out where it is. If it is to the left (less than 1/3 the screen width), use the first view. If it's in the middle, use the second view, etc.

Comment: I've got it all to work now, all three views work separately and I have the min and max. However, one final problem is that I have put this application on a UIScrollView. This means that when I try to swipe left or right to go to the next page, it thinks I'm changing the bars. How can I get it recognise only an upwards swipe, not a sideways swipe?

Comment: Check out there velocity of the gesture: `CGPoint velocity = [gestureRecognizer velocityInView:yourView];`, and you should be able to determine which direction it is moving in.

Answer (score 10):

## Swift version using UIPanGestureRecognizer

Using PanGesture added to UIView from Storyboard and delegate set to self.
UIView is attached to bottom of the screen.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var translation: CGPoint!
var startPosition: CGPoint! //Start position for the gesture transition
var originalHeight: CGFloat = 0 // Initial Height for the UIView
var difference: CGFloat!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    originalHeight = dragView.frame.height
}

@IBOutlet weak var dragView: UIView! // UIView with UIPanGestureRecognizer

@IBOutlet var gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

@IBAction func viewDidDragged(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == .began {
        startPosition = gestureRecognizer.location(in: dragView) // the postion at which PanGestue Started
    }

    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
        translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), in: self.view)
        let endPosition = sender.location(in: dragView) // the posiion at which PanGesture Ended
        difference = endPosition.y - startPosition.y
        var newFrame = dragView.frame
        newFrame.origin.x = dragView.frame.origin.x
        newFrame.origin.y = dragView.frame.origin.y + difference //Gesture Moving Upward will produce a negative value for difference
        newFrame.size.width = dragView.frame.size.width
        newFrame.size.height = dragView.frame.size.height - difference //Gesture Moving Upward will produce a negative value for difference
        dragView.frame = newFrame
    }

    if sender.state == .ended || sender.state == .cancelled {
        //Do Something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If my view attached to top of the screen and i want to increase height to bottom side then what i have to change in this code.

Answer (score 6):

This is my swift solution in doing it using autolayout and a height constraint on the view you want to resize, while setting a top and bottom limit based on the safe areas

```
private var startPosition: CGPoint!
private var originalHeight: CGFloat = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewDidDrag(_:)))
    resizableView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

@objc private func viewDidDrag(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began  {
        startPosition = sender.location(in: self.view)
        originalHeight = detailsContainerViewHeight.constant
    }

    if sender.state == .changed {
        let endPosition = sender.location(in: self.view)
        let difference = endPosition.y - startPosition.y
        var newHeight = originalHeight - difference

        if view.bounds.height - newHeight < topSafeArea + backButtonSafeArea {
            newHeight = view.bounds.height - topSafeArea - backButtonSafeArea
        } else if newHeight < routeDetailsHeaderView.bounds.height + bottomSafeArea {
            newHeight = routeDetailsHeaderView.bounds.height
        }

        resizableView.constant = newHeight
    }

    if sender.state == .ended || sender.state == .cancelled {
        //Do Something if interested when dragging ended.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex. Your solution helps me a lot.

Comment: what is detailsContainerViewHeight?