# make a UIScrollView draggable with finger?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimage

I'm having different layout buttons in main `ViewController` and if I select a layout which is having 2 frames,it presents next view with two `UIScrollView` and each `UIScrollView` having `UIImageView` and I need to drag those `UIScrollViews` and image also should be dragged when `UIScrollView` is dragging.Guys i'm struggling with this I'm not getting this.please someone help me my view looks like this

[image: first view is moving down like this i need to get and if i select second image it should also move up and down]

Comment: Can you tell in detail what you want to achieve here?

Comment: guys see first image is dragged down upon second image .if I select second image it should also dragged up and down.How to implement this.i'm struggling

Comment: yes sure thank you for your reply actually see that screen in middle of two images I'm having one straight line right .if I select first image using that separated line i should drag up and down .actually their positions should not be changed only their size should be increased or decreased based on dragging

Comment: Did you get me ?   i'm not getting how to explain my issue to you @SharmaVishal

Comment: Hey, Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427006/changing-height-of-uiview-in-reponse-to-finger-drag . Does it is the thing that you wants?

Comment: @SharmaVishal actually I'm having different views .how to get them and i know I have to use pan gesture but how to get their values

Comment: You can Simply Limit frames of your View And You can get your View in Self.view OR UISCrollView  with their TAG

Comment: ya I'm getting that using tag only .but the view is not changing using that code.is there any other process to follow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72204/discussion-between-sharma-vishal-and-suneha-chowdary).