# Slide up UIView following finger similar to Control Center in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableView` that is at the bottom of my main `UIViewController`, it currently only shows the top two rows. To show the rest I don't want it to scroll, I want the user to be able to "pull" the view up to reveal the additional 4 rows (can then swipe down on it to "push" it back into its original place), and I want the "pull" to be similar to how control center works in iOS. The spring that it has is really great.

Looks like I can add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to do the pull:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer * pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[self addGestureRecognizer:pan];

- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)aPan; {
  CGPoint currentPoint = [aPan locationInView:self];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.01f
                   animations:^{
                     CGRect oldFrame = _viewToChange.frame;
                     _viewToChange.frame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, currentPoint.y, oldFrame.size.width, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - currentPoint.y));
                   }];
}
```

[Ref this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427006/changing-height-of-uiview-in-reponse-to-finger-drag?rq=1).

Doing this *does* sort of work, but my `UITableView` flashes as you pull it up and it eventually disappears.

There is also no spring, and no way to set a "max" so that you can't pull up the view past a certain point.

Does anyone have ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Primarily opinion based. You could put your tableview inside a `UIScrollView` and handle gestures. Spring animations come standard with `UIView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how i write the `pan:`. `t` is tableView(initially user interaction is disabled). 40 in code is for more realistic look in `pan`. 200 is max value i used and 60 is min value. i directly add `t` to tableview with height 60 and increased the height with animation.

```
    - (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)aPan; {
    CGPoint currentPoint = [aPan locationInView:self.view];

    CGRect fr = t.frame;

    if ((currentPoint.y - fr.origin.y) < 40 && (fr.size.height <= 200) )
    {
        float nh = (currentPoint.y >= self.view.frame.size.height - 200) ? self.view.frame.size.height-currentPoint.y : 200;
        if (nh < 60) {
            nh = 60;
        }
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.01f animations:^{
            [t setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-nh, t.frame.size.width, nh)];
        }];
        if (nh == 200) {
            [t setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [t setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        }
    }

}
```

or without pan; with using tableview's scrollview delegate methods, when tableview begin dragging in closed state, opening the large mode and when tableview scroll to top sliding down

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"scroll");
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
            [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-200, t.frame.size.width, 200)];
        }];
    }
}
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
            [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-60, t.frame.size.width, 60)];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: This does seem to work, however once you let your finger up you cannot slide it back down.

Comment: @NicHubbard i tried up and down sliding and both worked.

Comment: It works when swiping up then pulling down, but not just swiping down. Strange.

Comment: @NicHubbard i couldn't produce the bug but one place it may be is `(currentPoint.y - fr.origin.y) < 40` replacing it with `fabs(currentPoint.y - fr.origin.y) < 40` may solve the problem.

Comment: What exactly is the `40` doing here?

Comment: it is for pan should be at most 40 points in y direction to top of tableview